# Generate input element to specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to add an input field to the specific div that was clicked.

I have a long list of divs like the following:

```
<div class="edit">1</div>
<div class="edit">10</div>
<div class="edit">22</div>
<div class="edit">5</div>
```

My javascript/jquery looks like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.edit', OnEdit);

function OnEdit(e) {
    $('.edit').append('<input type="text" name="amount"/>');
}
```

When I click, the problem is it adds the input field to all of the divs. I'd like it to only add the input field to the div that was specifically clicked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ThisBinding` or `this` in the callback, that is `OnEdit` will be pointing towards the current element which triggered the event.

So use `this` reference

```
function OnEdit(e) {
    $(this).append('<input type="text" name="amount"/>');
}
```

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you. I'll accept as soon as it's clickable.

Comment: @rotaercz glad to have helped :) And I'm not awesome, you're new to Stack Overflow. You'll find many more awesome people here :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code like this:

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
    $(this).append('<input type="text" name="amount"/>');
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uvf01p4d/)

Notes:

1. Bind the click event specifically to all divs with class `edit`
2. As pointed out by Amit, use the `$(this)` object to reference the specific div that triggered the click event, and append to that one.

Comment: I'm loading content using Ajax so it would become unbound. Thank you for the suggestion though.